# Chapter on the right side - How to turn it off?

Tags: page-breaking, chapters, document-classes, double-sided

As a documentclass I use `book`. Chapters always start on the right hand side. 
How can I turn it off? I don't want to have empty pages. I don't care on which side starts  new chapter.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count. This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!).

Comment: In case someone wants to disable this behaviour at some place in the document (and not globally) http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/31644/6865 could be a solution.

Answer (score 54):

Use the document class option `openany` or consider using the `report` class instead, where this is the default.

There are two related document class options:

- `openright`: makes chapters begin on right hand pages, default for the `book` class
- `openany`: makes chapters begin on the next available page, default for the `report` class

Also the margins are differently treated in `book` and `report`, which can be customized by options:

- `twoside`: double sided output style, for different inner and outer margin, default for the `book` class
- `oneside`: single sided output, for equal left and right margin, default for the `report` class and for `article`.

The default behavior can be changed by specifying such an option when loading the class, for example

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,openany]{book}
```

Besides the standard classes, further classes support these options, such as `amsbook`, `scrbook`, `screprt` and `memoir`. These classes may support further options, such as `openleft` in `memoir`.