# Forcing new chapter not to start on an odd page

Tags: page-breaking, chapters, document-classes, double-sided, amsbook

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Chapter on the right side - How to turn it off?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23625/chapter-on-the-right-side-how-to-turn-it-off)

I am using a document class `amsbook` which I like very much, except for one thing: each new chapter starts on an odd-numbered page. Therefore, it happens that I get a whole blank page in the text, which I dislike. Is it possible (and easy?) to force the new chapter to start immediately on the next page after the preceding chapter? Can it be made automatically?

Comment: Nice to see that the question has been answered and the answer has been accepted. So I closed it, marked it as a duplicate to [Chapter on the right side - How to turn it off?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23625/chapter-on-the-right-side-how-to-turn-it-off) because there's a comprehensive answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Simply add `openany` as an option to the documentclass, i.e.

```
\documentclass[openany]{amsbook}
```