# Appendices one after another

Tags: sectioning, page-breaking, appendices, double-sided

I am writing a document with the following documentclass:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,openright,12pt]{report}
```

Since I have some Appendices to the text and they are rather small, I was thinking if I could make them start one after another, without starting on the next page or without skipping any page (I need the openright behaviour for the rest of the text).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Besides combining all appendices as `\section`s into a single `\chapter`, you could a) disable the page breaking mechanism entirely for the appendix b) let `\cleardoublepage` to `\clearpage` in order to avoid blank pages between chapters. (Note: `\cleardoublepage` and `\clearpage` are internally used by `\chapter`.)

```
\documentclass[twoside,openright]{report}

\begin{document}

\chapter{bla}

Some text.

\cleardoublepage
\begingroup

% Alternative A
% \let\clearpage\relax

% Alternative B
\let\cleardoublepage\clearpage

\appendix

\chapter{blubb}

Some text.

\chapter{foo}

Some text.

\endgroup

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your example. But can I get the appendices starting on the same page? If I have two appendices let's say one paragraph long, I want them both on the same page. At the same time I must keep them at the chapter level in the TOC.

Comment: @Danilo: Just comment out the line under "Alternative B" in my example and comment in the line under "Alternative A".