# White pages before glossaries appendix

Tags: page-breaking, glossaries, appendices

When I use the `\printglossaries` inside the environment appendices I get two extra white pages I cannot get rid of. Do you know how to remove them?

Here a MWE which has such problem:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,titlepage,twoside,openright]{book}
\usepackage[makeindex,acronym,numberedsection,counter=chapter,nonumberlist]{glossaries} 
\usepackage[titletoc, page]{appendix}

\newacronym{abc}{ABC}{Alpha test}

\makeglossaries

\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter 1}
\gls{abc}


\begin{appendices}

\phantomsection\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Acronyms}
\printglossaries

\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The `\addcontentsline` is not necessary, in my point of view

Comment: The `appendices` environment is the cause of the additional blank pages

Comment: `\addcontentsline` it is not necessary, it's true. But doesn't affect the output.

Comment: I know who downvoted my post: I can compare rep changes before and after and the treacherous tracks it leaves ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I solved my question looking from another [post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/183097/renew-appendix-command-to-remove-blank-pages?rq=1). So if it is judged as a duplicate can be removed.

Here is a MWE with my desired output:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,titlepage,twoside,openright]{book}
\usepackage[makeindex,acronym,numberedsection,counter=chapter,nonumberlist]{glossaries} 
\usepackage[titletoc, page]{appendix}

\newacronym{abc}{ABC}{Alpha test}

\makeglossaries

\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter 1}
\gls{abc}


\begin{appendices}

\begingroup     
\let\clearpage\relax        
\printglossaries
\endgroup

\chapter{Appendix B}

\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```