# Suppress empty page before chapter

Tags: scrbook

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Chapter on the right side - How to turn it off?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23625/chapter-on-the-right-side-how-to-turn-it-off)

How do I remove empty pages before chapters? The following document renders as three pages; I just want two.

```
\documentclass[]{scrbook}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Foo}
\chapter{Bar}
\end{document}
```

I want to keep the `scrbook` template if possible.

Comment: Have you tried the `openany` documentclass option?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

By default the new chapters are opening on the right hand page. Use the `[openany]` class option if that is not desired.

```
\documentclass[openany]{scrbook}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Foo}
\chapter{Bar}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! I guess I'm too young to even consider that paper oddities such as two-side documents could play a role here.

Comment: @phihag: Its not just a paper oddity. Yes that is where it originated, but online viewers that can show two pages side by side might still make use of this.