# How to avoid a blank page when using \chapter*{}

Tags: formatting, chapters

So when using `\chapter*{}` this introduces a blank page before the next `\chapter*{}` I'm guessing it is because I am using a book format, tried putting it into a new group and clearing double page but this just messes up the whole format.

Is there a way of telling Latex not to include this page.

I include the code of this part of my document in particular:

```
\chapter*{Resumen}
\section*{Resumen}
Text Here
\section*{Palabras Clave}
a, b, c, d, e
\chapter*{}
\section*{Abstract}
Text Here
\section*{Key words}
a, b, c, d, e
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: [Chapter on the right side - How to turn it off?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/23625/4778)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If all chapters should be opened on any page, use the `openany` option (as has been recommended by `@alwin` already. If only particular chapters should open left, it's possible to switch off the openright feature by saying `\makeatletter\@openrightfalse\makeatother`. Don't forget to restore afterwards.

Some explanation by the definition of the `\chapter` command (taken from `book.cls`.

```
\newcommand\chapter{\if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi
                    \thispagestyle{plain}%
                    \global\@topnum\z@
                    \@afterindentfalse
                    \secdef\@chapter\@schapter}
```

As can be seen, each `\chapter` (regardless whether `\chapter` or `\chapter*` is used) uses the same starter code, i.e. it tests whether `\if@openright` expands to true and does a `\cleardoublepage`, so it will start on the next odd page. If `\if@openright` is false, it will use `\clearpage` and the chapter starts on the next page, (even or odd).

**Note** I don't recommend various opening styles throughout a document.

```
\documentclass{book}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\enableopenany}{%
  \@openrightfalse%
}
\newcommand{\disableopenany}{%
  \@openrighttrue%
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Foo}
\blindtext[20]


\enableopenany
\chapter*{Foobar}

\blindtext[17]


\disableopenany
\chapter{Foobar again}

\blindtext[20]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

If you don't want any blank pages in front of **all** your chapters, you can tell LaTeX to open chapters on any pages.

This is done by: `\documentclass[openany]{book}`

The default is `openright` which causes LaTeX to add the additional page  in order to make sure that the chapter opens on a right page.

There is additional detail in this answer here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/128336/51373

If you simply do not want an empty page between two specific chapters, my method would be: `\makeatletter\@openrightfalse` before the chapter to turn openright off, then turn it on again after the chapter with `\@openrighttrue\makeatother`.

Hope it solves your problem!

Comment: This would enable the `openany` feature for **all** chapters then

Comment: It wasn't clear from the question if Neptune wanted to clear the blank page from a single chapter, or all chapters. I assumed the latter, but I'll edit my answer just in case it was the former then